# Cannot find name 'REHYDRATE' even though it's imported in scope

Tags: typescript, redux

I have the following TypeScript 2.5 code:

```
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';

export interface Rehydrate {
    readonly type: REHYDRATE;
    readonly payload: AppState;
}
```

which errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/actions.ts:175:20
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'REHYDRATE'.
```

(Row 175 is the `readonly type: REHYDRATE;` one. ) Why? `REHYDRATE` is clearly in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (Row 175 is the readonly type: REHYDRATE; one. ) Why? REHYDRATE is clearly in scope.

Its imported as a variable, not a `Type`

## Fix

```
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';

export interface Rehydrate {
    readonly type: typeof REHYDRATE;
    readonly payload: AppState;
}
```

## More

The concept : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/declarationspaces.html